# Connecting Waveshare High-Precision AD/DA Board (ADS1256) to DE10-Nano Kit

Tags: c, spi, intel-fpga, digital-design

I'm currently working on an ECG project and I'm having some difficulties using the Waveshare High-Precision AD/DA Board (which has an ADS1256 ADC and is meant for use with RPI) with the Terasic DE10-Nano Kit.

I'm using an Altera SPI Master peripheral in Qsys with the following settings:

- SCLK rate: 20000
- Data Width: 8 bits
- Shift Direction: MSB first
- Clock Polarity: 0
- Clock Phase: 1
- No synchronizer stages

For the remaining required signals I'm using Avalon PIO:

- DRDY (Input)
- RST (output)
- PWR (output)

Additionally, there's a Nios2 CPU which makes use of `alt_avalon_spi_command` to send SPI commands and `IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA` to control the PIO.

The issue I'm experiencing, is that the DRDY signal is never asserted (it's expected to go LOW before being able to read data). I understand this signal should be used with a pull-up resistor; I've tried the following, neither of which worked:

1. Configure internal pull up on DE10-Nano GPIO pin
2. Use external pull up resistors (10K/56K)

I understand I should be able to read the Chip ID of the ADS1256, prior to configuring it. I first reset the device, as per:
https://github.com/waveshare/High-Precision-AD-DA-Board/blob/master/Jetson%20nano/ADS1256/C/obj/ADS1256.c#L39

```
    /* RESET */
    IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA( WAVESHARE_ADS_RST_BASE, HIGH );
    usleep(200);
    IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA( WAVESHARE_ADS_RST_BASE, LOW );
    usleep(200);
    IOWR_ALTERA_AVALON_PIO_DATA( WAVESHARE_ADS_RST_BASE, HIGH );
```

Then I wait for DRDY to go LOW and this never seems to happen, regardless of the above-mentioned setup for the pull up resistor:

```
alt_u8 ADS1256_wait_DRDY( void ) {
    for( int i=0; i<50; i++ ) {
        alt_u8 drdy = ADS1256_DRDY_get_level();
        if ( drdy == LOW ) {
            printf( "DRDY asserted\n" );
            return 0;
        } else {
            usleep( DELAY_DRDY );
        }
    }
    printf( "Timeout: DRDY not asserted.\n" );
    return -1;
}
```

I'm probing using a Hobby Components Logic Analyser. The pin connections are elaborated below:

```
AD/DA        RPI PIN       DE10-Nano   Location    Standard    HDL Signal        Direction  Logic Analyzer
==========================================================================================================
3v3          3v3           3v3                                                                  
GND          GND           GND                                                                             
MOSI         19 (GPIO 10)  GPIO_0(0)   PIN_V12     3.3V LVTTL  SPI_MOSI          OUT        D0                  
MISO         21 (GPIO 9)   GPIO_0(2)   PIN_W12     3.3V LVTTL  SPI_MISO          IN         D1 
SCK          23 (GPIO 11)  GPIO_0(4)   PIN_D8      3.3V LVTTL  SPI_SCK           OUT        D2 
P3 (CS_PIN)  15 (GPIO 22)  GPIO_0(1)   PIN_E8      3.3V LVTTL  SPI_SS_n(0)*      OUT        D3 
P1 (RST)     12 (GPIO 18)  GPIO_0(3)   PIN_D11     3.3V LVTTL  ADS_RST           OUT        D4  
P0 (DRDY)    11 (GPIO 17)  GPIO_0(6)   PIN_AE15    3.3V LVTTL  WAVESHARE_DRDY    IN         D5
```

The logic analyser output is as following:
[PulseView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS3qz.png)

Any help on how to set this up is much appreciated. Apologies if my post is not great, I'm fairly new to posting on these forums.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the pin assignments were not correct. After fixing these and testing with a different microcontroller instead of the AD/DA board, the DRDY is asserted, but the issue persists with the waveshare board. It looks like a board specific issues, so I've contacted the manufacturer for assistance.